# How to extract URL tag in Json using php

Tags: php, html, json, regex, match

I'm trying to extract url tag from given code :

```
(function(e,a){
    var t={
        "cdn_url":"https://f.vimeocdn.com",
        "view":1,
        "request":{
            "files":{
                "h264":{
                    "hd":{
                        "profile":113,
                        "origin":"level3",
                        "url":"https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3164/4/115821665/722085083.mp4?expires=1446817250&token=0cc7a9f36655f3a0afff3",
                        "cdn":"level3",
                        "height":720,
                        "width":1280,
                        "id":722085083,
                        "bitrate":2583,
                        "availability":114
                    },
                    "sd":{
                        "profile":112,
                        "origin":"level3",
                        "url":"https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3164/4/115821665/722083593.mp4?expires=1446817250&token=024b83dea6d2f4e4f57e1",
                        "cdn":"level3",
                        "height":360,
                        "width":640,
                        "id":722083593,
                        "bitrate":667,
                        "availability":114
                    }
                },
                "hls":{
                    "origin":"level3",
                    "all":"https://09-lvl3-hls.vimeocdn.com/1446820550-c34bde21acdff66dc5a0a7a4a701ba220774c80e/01/3164/4/115821665/master.m3u8",
                    "cdn":"level3"
                },
                "codecs":["h264"]
            },
            "ga_account":"UA-76641-35",
            "expires":3600,
            "timestamp":1446813350,
            "signature":"6e5fbd174b7b4503945ffa8ae800f4b5",
            "currency":"USD",
            "session":"60ee52a4f9a681617d768b7bf329c10867b53cfe1446813350",
            "cookie": {
                "scaling":1,
                "volume":1.0,
                "quality":null,
                "hd":null,
                "captions":null},
```

I am trying to extract the SD video URL this one from the above code:

```
https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3164/4/115821665/722083593.mp4?expires=1446817250&token=024b83dea6d2f4e4f57e1
```

I am using PHP for it can any one help !
I am trying to download the video but for that i first need the url of the SD video.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for. Do u want to extract url tag from that json above?

Comment: I want to extract the https:// url from the above text to download that video !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's all what you need, try

```
"url":"([^"]*)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/tZ1iV5/2

Example of usage in code:

```
$re = "/\"url\":\"([^\"]*)\"/"; 
$str = "(function(e,a){var t={\"cdn_url\":\"https://f.vimeocdn.com\",\"view\":1,\"request\":{\"files\":{\"h264\":{\"hd\":{\"profile\":113,\"origin\":\"level3\",\"url\":\"https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3164/4/115821665/722085083.mp4?expires=1446817250&token=0cc7a9f36655f3a0afff3\",\"cdn\":\"level3\",\"height\":720,\"width\":1280,\"id\":722085083,\"bitrate\":2583,\"availability\":114},\"sd\":{\"profile\":112,\"origin\":\"level3\",\"url\":\"https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3164/4/115821665/722083593.mp4?expires=1446817250&token=024b83dea6d2f4e4f57e1\",\"cdn\":\"level3\",\"height\":360,\"width\":640,\"id\":722083593,\"bitrate\":667,\"availability\":114}},\"hls\":{\"origin\":\"level3\",\"all\":\"https://09-lvl3-hls.vimeocdn.com/1446820550-c34bde21acdff66dc5a0a7a4a701ba220774c80e/01/3164/4/115821665/master.m3u8\",\"cdn\":\"level3\"},\"codecs\":[\"h264\"]},\"ga_account\":\"UA-76641-35\",\"expires\":3600,\"timestamp\":1446813350,\"signature\":\"6e5fbd174b7b4503945ffa8ae800f4b5\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"session\":\"60ee52a4f9a681617d768b7bf329c10867b53cfe1446813350\",\"cookie\":{\"scaling\":1,\"volume\":1.0,\"quality\":null,\"hd\":null,\"captions\":null},"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the value you need

[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/548dd364560d7a62b4fbea78efd5292601238a5b)

Comment: Can you provide me full preg_match code to apply for this in PHP.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0891043e7b9e54b526f34004372622ce0a41a5da

Comment: Its from the HD part. I need from SD part

Comment: pick `$matches[1][1]` then

Comment: Are you sure you are using `$matches[1][1]` variable? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/548dd364560d7a62b4fbea78efd5292601238a5b

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex to grab it:

```
"sd":.*?"url":"([^"]*)"
```

The URL ends up in the first (and only) capture group.

But this is a **very crude way** of getting it. I suggest you get the JSON-object and use `json_decode` to get the value you want. (Your example HTML isn't complete so I can't tell you what a regex to get the JSON-object would look like though.)

Regards